# (How to Fix) Site URL shows as cdn.mysite.com instead of www.mysite.com

Tags: wordpress, url, cdn, prefix

When I google my site, the google result shows my site's URL as **cdn.mysite.com** instead of **www.mysite.com.**

How can I fix this? I am currently using Amazon cloudfront CDN for a wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a canonical header option that you can enable in Cloudfront so that all of your CDN assets have a canonical link to the original asset on your origin server? Otherwise, if you don't have the canonical header enabled, search engines might see this as duplicate content.

You should also verify your cdn subdomain within Google Webmasters.

Additionally, I'd also recommend checking out a [CDN SEO guide](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/cdn-seo-indexing-images/) to double check other aspects of your CDN SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer.

Actually, it turned out my hosting company was blocking some IPs coming from Google. Now that those IPs are unblocked, the google result shows the correct prefix, which is www.mysite.com

Thank you